# Exporting public and private keys to a new machine: error!

Tags: 14.04, evolution, gnupg

I am using 16.04.1-Ubuntu. I backed up two files: Edson_private.key and Edson_public.key to a new machine.

I tried this: [Moving/Copying your PGP Keys](https://www.phildev.net/pgp/gpg_moving_keys.html)

But in Evolution mail I got: No secret key gpg: signing failed: No secret key ", you may need to select different mail options.

[image: Evolution 1]

[image: error]

[image: keys fingerprints]

[image: COnfiguration]

What Should I do? It is driving me crazy!
output of :

```
gpg --list-secret-keys

ls -l ~/.gnupg
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC23v.jpg

output of gpg --version:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 1.4.20
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, RSA-E, RSA-S, ELG-E, DSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: MD5, SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

output of gpg2 --version:

```
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
libgcrypt 1.6.5
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Home: ~/.gnupg
Supported algorithms:
Pubkey: RSA, ELG, DSA, ECDH, ECDSA, EDDSA
Cipher: IDEA, 3DES, CAST5, BLOWFISH, AES, AES192, AES256, TWOFISH,
        CAMELLIA128, CAMELLIA192, CAMELLIA256
Hash: SHA1, RIPEMD160, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, SHA224
Compression: Uncompressed, ZIP, ZLIB, BZIP2
```

Comment: What's the output of `gpg --list-secret-keys` and the directory listing of `~/.gnupg`, either by running `ls -l ~/.gnupg` or some GUI screenshot?

Comment: @Jens Erat: the output: http://imgur.com/a/ESiJV

Comment: It is mush easier simply to copy the keys.

Comment: @Pilot6 : how?  Copy to where?

Comment: From `~/.gnugpg` to `~/.gnugpg`

Comment: @Pilot6: I  don't understand! From/to the same directory?

Comment: From one machine to another.

Comment: @Pilot6: I formated the machine!

Comment: @Pilot6: Edson_private.key and Edson_public.key are the backup!

Comment: Please do never paste textual content as screenshots, have a look at the [FAQ] on how to edit your question with console output formatted as code instead. Images are not searchable, nor do they provide copy-paste or extended textual analysis options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GnuPG 1.4 and 2.0 expects public and private keys in `~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg` respective `~/.gnupg/pubring.gpg`. `Edson_private.key` and `Edson_public.key` are no standard keyrings that are created by GnuPG, also not for backups. You must have created them on your own somehow.

Given your `pubring.gpg` and `secring.gpg` files are already seem to have some content, the easiest solution is probably to use GnuPG's import function:

```
gpg --import ~/.gnupg/Edson_private.gpg
gpg --import ~/.gnupg/Edson_public.gpg
```

You might have to [issue ultimate trust on your own key](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/129474/19837) afterwards (you won't do any harm by applying ultimate trust although it is already set-up, so in doubt, just apply the procedure described).

Update: I forgot that Ubuntu 16.04 is already installing GnuPG 2.1, which merged the separate secret keyring into the public keyring. Thunderbird and Enigmail rely on `gpg2`/GnuPG 2.x for their operation, so it picked up GnuPG 2.1 which searches `pubring.gpg` for private keys -- while `gpg --import` had GnuPG 1.4 import the secret keys to `secring.gpg`. This results in unexpected issues like the one you have again and again.

Solution: import the private key file again, but this time using `gpg2 --import`. While still on Ubuntu 16.04, try not to use `gpg` any more to stick to a single secret keyring -- future Ubuntu releases ship GnuPG 2.1 as `gpg` (and GnuPG 1.4 as `gpg1`), which will prevent those oddities.

Comment: I have 3 private keys for 3 different emails. How can I use them  simultaneously?

Comment: I think I dont know how to backup correctly the keys to another machine!

Comment: gpg --import ~/.gnupg/Edson_public.key  ->
Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1

Comment: gpg --import ~/.gnupg/Edson_private.key  ->
gpg: key 67427080: already in secret keyring

Comment: error -> http://imgur.com/a/BV8Pl

Comment: What's the output of `gpg --version`, `gpg2 --version`?

Comment: Please don't add additional information in comments. Edit your question, so it contains all relevant information instead (you can still comment of course you extended the question). Also as I already noted above -- _never_ post console output and other textual content as images, as images can neither be searched nor copy-pasted. Copying output from the terminal is very easy and the [FAQ] explains how you can format text as code.

Comment: done! I edited the question.

Comment: I already added an update to the answer some hours ago, did you already see it? It wasn't a big deal in this case with the image, it's just a generally discouraged thing to post textual information as images. Consider URLs, error numbers or text -- often, people able to answer still have to verify something by searching google or looking up something, and having to type cryptic text instead of just copying it is tedious and very error-prone.

Comment: yes, but I have already done: 
gpg --import

What should I do?

Comment: Watch out for the 2 in `gpg2` (vs `gpg`) -- as explained in the update, GnuPG 2.1 stores secret keys in another file compared to GnuPG 1.4 and GnuPG 2.0. `gpg` and `gpg2` don't share the same secret keyring any more in Ubuntu 16.04, and Enigmail relies on `gpg2` and thus another key store than you imported the secret keys into.

Comment: I have 3 private keys for 3 different emails but only one is working.

Comment: it worked!  I did   gpg2 --edit-key 81422478  trust